# Button selector error

Tags: android, android-studio, button

I received error when i tried to create a button selector on Android Studio.
Compiler shows me red exclamation on this line    `<item android:drawable="@drawable/button_design"`

Here's button_selector.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
   <item android:drawable="@drawable/button_design"
       android:state_pressed="true"
       />
</selector>
```

Here's button_design.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle">
      <gradient
          android:startColor="#29B6F6"
          android:endColor="#0288D1"
          android:angle="90"
          android:type="linear"
    />
      <corners
          android:radius="5dp"
          />
    <stroke
        android:color="#FFFFFF"
        android:width="3dp"
     />
</shape>
```

Comment: Make sure that your `button_design.xml` is in the `drawable` folder in the `layout` folder check it.

Comment: It's already in drawable folder

Comment: @H. Philips hover mouse on it what is error say read it.

Comment: It doesnt show anything only a red exclamation appears begging of the code.When i hovered the mouse it doesnt show anything

Comment: did you `clean` the project. because your code is working fine I test it..

Comment: In `Android Studio` click on `Build` menu and select `Clean Project`.

Comment: I've cleaned the project still there's an exclamation but program works perfectly.

Comment: do one thing Click on `File` menu Select `Invalidate Caches and Restart`. and select `Restart`. may be now it solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

check the images are in different version folder than your running emulator.

[that is the problem of occuring a error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2run8.gif)

Paste that images into drawable folder not any drawable version folder.